# Extracting items from array using variable sliding window in Python

Tags: python

I have an array of digits: `array = [1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 4.0, 1.0]`

I would like to create a function that extracts sequences of digits from the input array and appends to one of two lists depending on defined conditions being met

The first condition `f` specifies the number of places to look ahead from index `i` and check if a valid index exists. If true, append `array[i]` to list1. If false, append to list2.

I have implemented it as follows:

```
def somefunc(array, f):
    list1, list2 = [], []

    for i in range(len(array)):
        if i + f < len(array):
            list1.append(array[i])
        else:
            list2.append(array[i])
            
    return list1, list2
```

This functions correctly as follows:
`somefunc(array,f=1)` returns `([1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 4.0], [1.0])`
`somefunc(array,f=2)` returns `([1.0, 1.0, 2.0], [4.0, 1.0])`
`somefunc(array,f=3)` returns `([1.0, 1.0], [2.0, 4.0, 1.0])`

However, I would like to add a second condition to this function, `b`, that specifies the window length for previous digits to be summed and then appended to the lists according to the `f` condition above.

The logic is this:

- iterate through array and at each index `i` check if `i`+`f` is a valid index.
- If true, append the sum of the previous `b` digits to `list1`
- If false, append the sum of the previous `b` digits to `list2`
- If the length of window `b` isn't possible (i.e. `b=2` when `i=0`) continue to next index.

With both `f` and `b` conditions implemented. I would expect:
`somefunc(array,f=1, b=1)` returns `([1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 4.0], [1.0])`
`somefunc(array,f=1, b=2)` returns `([2.0, 3.0, 6.0], [5.0])`
`somefunc(array,f=2, b=2)` returns `([2.0, 3.0], [6.0, 5.0])`

<s>My first challenge is implementing the `b` condition. I cannot seem to figure out how.</s> *see edit below*

I also wonder if there is a more efficient approach than the iterative method I have begun?

Given only the `f` condition, I know that the following functions correctly and would bypass the need for iteration:

```
def somefunc(array, f):
    return array[:-f], array[-f:]
```

However, I again don't know how to implement the `b` condition in this approach.

---

*Edit*

I have managed an iterative solution which implements the `f` and `b` conditions:

```
def somefunc(array, f, b):
    list1, list2 = [], []

    for i in range(len(array)):
        if i >= (b-1):
            if i + f < len(array):
                list1.append(sum(array[i+1-b: i+1]))
            else:
                list2.append(sum(array[i+1-b: i+1]))
            
    return list1, list2
```

However, the indexing syntax feels horrible and I so I am certain there must be a more elegant solution. Also, anything with improved runtime would really be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two minor improvements you could implement in your code:

```
def somefunc(array, f, b):
    list1, list2 = [], []
    size = len(array) # Will only measure the length of the array once
    
    for i in range(b-1, size): # By starting from b-1 you can remove an if statement
        if i + f < size: # We use the size here
            list1.append(sum(array[i+1-b: i+1]))
        else:
            list2.append(sum(array[i+1-b: i+1]))
            
    return list1, list2
```

Edit:
An ever better solution would be to add the new digit and substract the last at each iteration. This way you don't need to redo the whole sum each iteration:

```
def somefunc(array, f, b):
    list1, list2 = [], []
    value = 0
    size = len(array)
    
    for i in range(b-1, size):
        if value != 0:
            value = value - array[i-b] + array[i] # Get the last value, add the value at index i and remove the value at index i-b
        else:
            value = sum(array[i+1-b: i+1])
        if i + f < size:
            list1.append(value)
        else:
            list2.append(value)
            
    return list1, list2
```